# Abstract builder constructing immutable object

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, reflection, builder

I have following code implementing abstract builder (as in effective java book):

```
interface I {
    I ret();
}

abstract class A implements I {

    private String s = "";

    A(Builder b) {
        s = b.s;
    }

    @Override
    public I ret() {
        String s = "some new string from calc.";
        //HERE I NEED TO CONSTRUCT class B
        //THIS IS PROBLEMATIC LINE BELOW <<<<--------------------------------------
        return new Builder<>().withString(s).build();
    }

    static abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {

        String s = "";

        T withString(String s) {
            this.s = s;
            return self();
        }

        protected abstract A build();

        //simulated self-type idiom
        protected abstract T self();
    }
}

class B extends A {

    private B(A.Builder b) {
        super(b);
    }

    static class Builder extends A.Builder<Builder> {

        @Override
        protected B build() {
            return new B(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected Builder self() {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is small use-case

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    I b = new B.Builder().withString("bclass").build();
    I b2 = b.ret(); //<---- this one should construct new immutable B
}
```

What I want to do is - from `ret()` method in the class `A`, I would like to construct immutable object that is ignorant of parent type - so in my example it would be new class `B` that has new inner string.

Problem is that class `A` does not know about class `B`, since `B` is it's parent.

Is something like this possible without resorting for generics?

If I use mutable class, it would be as simple as `this.s = newS;`.

**UPDATE**

```
abstract class A implements I {

    private String s = "";

    A(Builder b) {
        s = b.s;
    }

    @Override
    public I ret() {
        String s = "SOME NEW STING FROM CALCULATION";
        return builder().withString(s).build();
    }

    abstract Builder<?> builder();

    static abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {

        String s = "";

        T withString(String s) {
            this.s = s;
            return self();
        }

        protected abstract A build();

        //simulated self-type idiom
        protected abstract T self();
    }
}

class B extends A {

    B(A.Builder b) {
        super(b);
    }

    @Override
    Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    static class Builder extends A.Builder<Builder> {

        @Override
        protected B build() {
            return new B(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected Builder self() {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does a builder add here? Can't you just invoke a (private?) constructor directly?

Comment: I removed a lot of code so it is cleaner. Just concentrated on my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide an abstract method in `A` to construct a suitable instance of `Builder`:

```
abstract Builder<A> toBuilder();
```

Then implement that in the concrete subclasses, and invoke:

```
return toBuilder().withString(s).build();
```

Comment: thanks, this looks good. I hope that this line `abstract Builder<?> builder();` is how it should be done? I updated example with new code.